# How to define Placeholder's type in Ramda in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ramda.js

```
const greet = R.replace('{name}', R.__, 'Hello, {name}!');
greet('Alice'); //=> 'Hello, Alice!'
```

The above code is copy from [Ramda's documment](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#__), when a pate it in typescript environment, typescript complains:

> Argument of type 'Placeholder' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'string | ((match: string, ...args: readonly any[]) => string)'.
>   Type 'Placeholder' is not assignable to type '(match: string,
> ...args: readonly any[]) => string'.     Type 'Placeholder' provides
> no match for the signature '(match: string, ...args: readonly any[]):
> string'.

How to solve this complaint?

Comment: That's interesting. But it sounds the current defined doesn't support placeholder though. You might have to skip this check for now until they support curry function accordingly

Comment: @ tmhao2005 Yes that is what i am thinking, thank you

Comment: If you're interested in curry function typing, here's a very good article taking about that. Seems like the author is also keen to merge his work to as official type: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/typescript-curry-ramda-types-f747e99744ab/

Comment: @tmhao2005 That's a nice article, thanks